# free membership on register by domain

Tags: php, wordpress

On our site we have it so that our posts are only visible to paid subscribers. But we want users with certain email address domains to, when they register, be able to view every post we have without having to pay for it. We use the paid memberships pro plugin on wordpress and they have these to bits of code in their documentation that allows us to automatically assign membership on sign up and to restrict sign up to certain domains. They both work as intended on their own but when we tried the combine them it didn't work. We don't really know any php, so we're just moving lines around to where we think makes sense. The third bit of code is our attempt to combine them. Does anyone have any suggestions on how they can be put together?

```
/* When registering, add the member to a specific membership level 
 * @param integer $user_id*/
//Disables the pmpro redirect to levels page when user tries to register
add_filter("pmpro_login_redirect", "__return_false");
function my_pmpro_default_registration_level($user_id) {
//Give all members who register membership level 1
pmpro_changeMembershipLevel(1, $user_id);
}
add_action('user_register', 'my_pmpro_default_registration_level');





function restrict_email($value)
{
    $email = $_REQUEST['bemail'];

    if(!check_validity($email))
    {
        global $pmpro_msg, $pmpro_msgt;
        $pmpro_msg = "Please enter a valid email address";
        $pmpro_msgt = "pmpro_error";
        $value = false;
    }
    return value;
}
add_filter('pmpro_registration_checks','restrict_email', 10, 1);
//Taken from: http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-extract-domain-name-from- 
an-e-mail-address-string.html
function getDomainFromEmail($email)
{
// Get the data after the @ sign
    $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);

    return $domain;
}
function check_validity($email)
{
    $domain = getDomainFromEmail($email);

    $valid_domains = array("yahoo.com", "*.gmail.com", "*.domain.uk");
    foreach($valid_domains as $valid_domain)
    {
        $components = explode(".", $valid_domain);
        $domain_to_check = explode(".", $domain);

        if($components[0] == "*" && sizeof($domain_to_check > 2))
        {
            if($components[1] == $domain_to_check[1] && $components[2] == $domain_to_check[2])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!(strpos($valid_domain, $domain) === false))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}





add_filter("pmpro_login_redirect", "__return_false");
function restrict_email($value)
{   $email = $_REQUEST['bemail'];

    if(!check_validity($email))
    {   global $pmpro_msg, $pmpro_msgt;
        $pmpro_msg = "Please enter a valid email address";
        $pmpro_msgt = "pmpro_error";
        $value = false;
    }
    return value;
}
add_filter('pmpro_registration_checks','restrict_email', 10, 1);
function getDomainFromEmail($email)
{    // Get the data after the @ sign
    $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
    return $domain;
}
function my_pmpro_default_registration_level($user_id) {
function check_validity($email)
{   $domain = getDomainFromEmail($email);

    $valid_domains = array("ipqpubs.com", "ipqpubs.org");
    foreach($valid_domains as $valid_domain)
    {   $components = explode(".", $valid_domain);
        $domain_to_check = explode(".", $domain);

        if($components[0] == "*" && sizeof($domain_to_check > 2))
        {   if($components[1] == $domain_to_check[1] && $components[2] == $domain_to_check[2])
            {
                pmpro_changeMembershipLevel(1, $user_id);
            }}
        else
        {
            if(!(strpos($valid_domain, $domain) === false))
                return true;
        }}

    return true;
}
add_action('user_register', 'my_pmpro_default_registration_level');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run pmpro_changeMembershipLevel(1, $user_id) when the domain is ipqbubs.com or .org, you have a couple of issues here. For one, you'll want to put that function under the strpos line. As it is, that function will never run because nothing in your valid_domains array contains "*" (represents a subdomain). Second, $user_id is not in scope for check_validity. Please try something more like this:

```
function my_pmpro_default_registration_level($email, $user_id) {
    $domain = getDomainFromEmail($email);
    $valid_domains = array("ipqpubs.com", "ipqpubs.org");
    foreach($valid_domains as $valid_domain) {
       if(strpos($valid_domain, $domain) !== false)
       {
          pmpro_changeMembershipLevel(1, $user_id);
          return true;
        }
     }
}
```